# Bundling - Application Path error

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css, bundling-and-minification

I use the [Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.web.optimization/) nuget package for css and js bundling and minification.

I create a bundle in this path `~/bundles/shared.css`

```
BundleTable.Bundles.Add(
    new StyleBundle("~/bundles/shared.css")
       .Include(
        "~/Style/DevexpressAdapter.css",
        "~/Style/Site.css",
        "~/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/css/flick/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css"));
```

When I run the project on localhost (with CTRL+F5 from Visual Studio) it runs well. If i hit `http://localhost/bundles/shared.css` then I get the minified and combined css for all the files I have added to the bundle.

But in the published location, it doesn't work.

The site runs at the `http://192.168.1.8/MyApp/` address.

when I take a look at the html, the minified bundle's url is `src="/MyApp/bundles/shared.css"`. But if i hit `http://192.168.1.8/MyApp/bundles/shared.css` i get a resource not found error. If I also hit `http://192.168.1.8/MyApp/MyApp/bundles/shared.css` i get the same error.

What is going on, and how do I solve this problem? I can't touch anything at the production server. I can only copy the files to a shared folder I have access to.

It seem's the bundle's url is not resolved correctly.
I would expect that the rendered bundle's url would not containt the `/MyApp/` part

Answer (score -1):

Instead of providing the virtual path, try using the physical path with following method

Server.MapPath().

Comment: A Bundle's path must always be application relative url Not a physical path, otherwise an exception is thrown. Also, a bundle is not an actual file residing somewhere on the disk. It is content that is created and returned to the response on the fly when the bundle's url is accessed by the browser.